# Filter duplicate sequence of rows

Tags: r, data.table

(Note i was surprised not finding a similar question but i am happy to remove this one if i am mistaken).

I have the following sample dataset.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(val = c(1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3), id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))
```

Group with id=1 has the same values for val (1,2,3) as group with id=3. I would like to filter out this "duplicate" values in group id=3.

My desired output is:

```
> dt
   val id
1:   1  1
2:   2  1
3:   3  1
4:   0  2
5:   2  2
6:   4  2
```

I only came up with dirty workarounds like taking the sum: `dt[, filter:= sum(val) , by = id]` and remove duplicates, but then the values for id = 2 would also disappear.

Note: If values for id=3 would be 1,3,2 (so same values but different order, the rows should not be removed),..so order matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to string, remove duplicates and merge, i.e.

```
merge(dt, unique(dt[, .(new = toString(val)), id], by = 'new'))[,new := NULL][]
#   id val
#1:  1   1
#2:  1   2
#3:  1   3
#4:  2   0
#5:  2   2
#6:  2   4
```

We can avoid `merge` by pulling the `id`s and using `%in%`, i.e.

```
i1 <- unique(dt[, .(new = toString(val)), id], by = 'new')[, id]
dt[id %in% i1,]
#   val id
#1:   1  1
#2:   2  1
#3:   3  1
#4:   0  2
#5:   2  2
#6:   4  2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a data.table specific approach, but it would work:

```
x = split(dt$val, dt$id)
dt[!id %in% names(x[duplicated(x)])]
#   val id
#1:   1  1
#2:   2  1
#3:   3  1
#4:   0  2
#5:   2  2
#6:   4  2
```

It might be not optimal in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `data.table`:

```
dt <- dt[, pat := paste(val, collapse = "/"), by = id][
  , .SD[which.min(rleid(pat))], by = .(pat, val)][, pat := NULL]
```

Output:

```
   val id
1:   1  1
2:   2  1
3:   3  1
4:   0  2
5:   2  2
6:   4  2
```